# RegEx for Dynamic URL Goals settings

Tags: regex, google-analytics, dynamic-url, goal-tracking

I have tried to work this RegEx to set up a goal in GA for 2 days, but I cannot get my head around it...

The URL format is like this:

```
/purchase.php?cDd=1&transaction_id=xxxxxxx&verify=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=&method=creditcard&type=purchase
```

transaction_id= is populated with a sept of numbers
`verify=` is populated by a string of numbers, letters in both caps and lower case

Basically I would like to only match URLs which finish by `&method=creditcard&type=purchase`

I have tried to just put `&method=creditcard&type=purchase` but it does retrieve other URLs too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put a `$` sign at the end of your regex.

This way you enforce to only match url's that end with `&method=creditcard&type=purchase`

```
^/purchase.php\?cDd=1&transaction_id=[0-9]*&verify=[a-zA-Z0-9]*=&method=creditcard&type=purchase$
```

or

```
&method=creditcard&type=purchase$
```

would do the trick

Comment: @gaaustralia: If this answer solves your problem, you can show your appreciation by accepting it (click the checkmark on the left), and (as soon as your reputation climbs over 15) also upvoting it.

Answer (score -2):

For any dynamic URL

```
^/(.*)&method=creditcard&type=purchase$
```