# RegEx for dynamic URLs in Analytics Goal funnel

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I am trying to set up a Google Analytics goal funnel for the various steps in a checkout process.

The final URL looks something like:

> word/something/confirmation/000548693

or

> word/something/confirmation/01857303

etc.

I don't want to set up an incorrect goal for my client, however my guess is that the expression should look like:

```
word/something/confirmation*
```

What RegEx is required to track a dynamic URL such as this that can be used in Google Analytics' goal funnel?

For reference, this particular feature in Analytics does not let you choose "begins with" or "contains" etc, like it does with various other features, it simply asks for the URL. Also worth noting [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881098/regex-for-dynamic-url-goals-settings), but is not the same as my question.

Comment: The funnel steps take the operator of the destinantion, so if you set the goal destination settings to "regex" this will apply to the steps as well.  I guess the question is on-topic by virtue of "regex" being a kind of code, but you'd need to provide some more information (while we know how the destination looks you do not say how the funnel steps urls look, so what should the regex match ? And if you do not have multiple steps you can simply disable the funnel).

Comment: A regex for `word/something/confirmation*` could be `word/something/confirmation/?.*`, or if there are always digits after `confirmation`, you might want to use `word/something/confirmation/[0-9]+`.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, Looks like what I'm after. Just to confirm, the `*` should exist at the end? My (incorrect) assumption was the RegEx would simply be the `*`. Or should the RegEx simply have `/?.` at the end?

Comment: `.*` matches 0+ characters other than a newline. A `*` is a quantifier, an operator that repeats matching of the preceding atom it quantifies. `/?` matches 1 or 0 `/` symbols as `?` is a quantifier matching 1 or 0 occurrences of the quantified atom (unit, subpattern, what you call it). `[0-9]` matches any 1 digit, with `+`, it matches 1 or more digits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that `word/something/confirmation*` - if passed to a regex engine - will try to match `word/something/confirmatio` + 0 or more `n` because `*` is a special *operator* called a *quantifier*  that repeats matching of the preceding atom it quantifies.

So, what you really can use is `word/something/confirmation($|/.*)` where `($|/.*)` matches the end of string (`$`) or `/` followed with 0+ any characters but a newline.

If you plan to match URLs with `word/something/confirmation/` followed with digits, you need a regex like

```
word/something/confirmation/[0-9]+
```

Where `[0-9]+` matches 1 or more (as `+` is also a quantifier matching 1 or more characters matching the preceding quantified subpattern).

If you are just interested in URLs with `word/something/confirmation`, you might want to make sure no `someword/something/confirmation123` does not get matched. You need to set boundaries with

```
(^|\W)word/something/confirmation($|\W)
```

Where `(^|\W)` matches the start of string (`^`) or any non-word letter (not `A-Z`, nor `a-z`, `0-9`, or `_`) and `($|\W)` matches the end of string (`$`) or a non-word character.

Comment: Wiktor, using your explanation, to track a URL containing multiple parameters, but only caring for the value of the first parameter in the chain (for example, `page.html?first=X&second=Y&third=Z`), would I use the pattern `page.html?first=X($|&.*)`?

Comment: I'd use `page\.html\?first=X($|&.*)`. You need to escape the `?` and `.` to treat them as literal symbols. `?` means *match 1 or 0 occurrences*, and `.` matches any symbol but a newline.

Answer (score 1):

If you literally only need a URL starting with word/something/confirmation/ then the regex is:

```
^word/something/confirmation/
```

Comment: Can I assume this would work with multiple URL parameters as well? So, if I have a URL like `page.html?first=X&second=Y`, and I only care about the value of `first` in my funnel steps, could I use `^page.html?first=1`, `^page.html?first=2`, etc.?

Comment: `^` means `starts here`, so `^page.html?first=1` would accept any URL that began with `page.html?first=1`. This would normally work for what you want, however it's not the same as requiring that `first` equals 1; if a preceding parameter crept in, it would fail; for example it would not match the page `page.html?ninja=true&first=1`